# finding distance between BLE devices using RSSI

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

I am working on a project which requires two BLE devices(a ble tag and a smart watch) to exchange data only when they are within 50cm to 100cm.
I could find i can use RSSI to find the distance between them.

Can anybody tell me how exactly i can do this.

I need good papers on finding distance using RSSI

Comment: There is no exact formula to calculate it. It depends on a myriad of factors. Make some experiments and determine a threshold value. You shouldn't spend much effort in it as the measurement has a high error ratio.

Comment: But this application is expected to be working in different environments. Will fixing threshold not affect this?

Comment: Unless you can tolerate a degree of variability in the activation distance, you have a broken requirement.